# How to display links to images from three models?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

There are 3 django models:

Basic model describing the job model:

```py
class Homework(models.Model):
    date_to = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    lesson = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    group = models.TextField(max_length=10)
    body_text = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    answer_text = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

Job photo model:

```py
class Body_Images(models.Model):
    body_homework = models.ForeignKey(Homework, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/homework/body')
```

And the model of the photo of the answers to the task

```py
class Answers_Images(models.Model):
    answer_homework = models.ForeignKey(Homework, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/homework/answers')
```

There are also three serializers

```py
class GetHomeworkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    body_image = GetHomeworkSerializerBodyImages(many=True)
    answer_image = GetHomeworkSerializerAnswersImages(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Homework
        fields = ('date_to',
                  'date_created',
                  'lesson',
                  'group',
                  'body_text',
                  'answer_text',
                  'body_image',
                 'answer_image')

class GetHomeworkSerializerAnswersImages(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answer_homework = serializers.RelatedField(source='Homework', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Answers_Images
        fields = ('answer_homework', 'answer_image',)

class GetHomeworkSerializerBodyImages(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    body_homework = serializers.RelatedField(source='Homework', read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Body_Images
        fields = ('body_homework', 'body_image')
```

I get an error when trying to get data

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `body_image` on serializer `GetHomeworkSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Homework` instance.
```

Original exception text was: `'Homework' object has no attribute 'body_image'`.

How can I get links to images from Body_Images and Answers_Images in one request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class GetHomeworkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    body_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_body_image')
    answer_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_answer_image')

    def get_body_image(self, instance):
        return GetHomeworkSerializerBodyImages(instance.body_images_set.all(), many=True).data

    def get_answer_image(self, instance):
        return GetHomeworkSerializerAnswerImages(instance.answers_images_set.all(), many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Homework
        fields = ('date_to',
                  'date_created',
                  'lesson',
                  'group',
                  'body_text',
                  'answer_text',
                  'body_image',
                  'answer_image')


class GetHomeworkSerializerAnswersImages(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Answers_Images
        fields = ('answer_image',)


class GetHomeworkSerializerBodyImages(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Body_Images
        fields = ('body_image',)
```

Comment: I got 'Homework' object has no attribute 'body_image_set' error

Comment: Yes, it should be `body_images_set`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!